# sharing class instance across classes in PHP

Tags: php, class, oop, object

I'm looking for a better solution to the one below.

I want to start logging from a main script which calls multiple classes to carry out various tasks.
I want all called classes to share the logging instance and add messages to the log.

For example:

Main Script:

```
<?php

include 'log.php'
include 'classA.php'
include 'classB.php'

// start new logs
$log = new log('my_log_file.log');
$log->addMessage('log added outside any classes');

// continue loggin within other classes

$task_a = new classA($log);

$task_b = new classB($log);
```

classA:

```
<?php

class classA {

function __construct($log="") {

  if(is_object($log)) {
    $log->AddMessage("log added from within classA");
  }

}

}
```

What's a better way to do this?

Comment: Usually you then just use a DIC (dependency injection container). But what you're doing is the right direction to go.

Comment: There are probably a ton of lazier, but not so many better ways.

Comment: Here's a good article regarding the topic: http://fabien.potencier.org/article/11/what-is-dependency-injection

Comment: Thanks for the feedback bwoebi, it's good to know I wasn't running with a totally crazy idea.

Comment: Yoshi, thanks for the article link - nice simple example showing pretty much what I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some nice responses folks, thanks for that. For my requirements, I'm sticking with what I originally have as nothing else proposed better matched what I already have.

Answer (score 1):

You could think about creating Registry class and put object of log to them

```
<?php

include 'registry.php';
include 'log.php';
include 'classA.php';
include 'classB.php';

// start new logs
$registry = new registry();
$registry->addLogger(new log('my_log_file.log'));
$registry->getLogger->addMessage('log added outside any classes');

// continue loggin within other classes

$task_a = new classA($registry);

$task_b = new classB($registry);
```

class a.php

```
<?php

class classA {

function __construct($registry="") {

  if(is_object($registry)) {
    $registry->getLogger()->AddMessage("log added from within classA");
  }

}

}
```

What's the gain? If you decide you need to pass to other classes other objects as for example database connection, application configuration or others, you simple modify registry, add to registry new object (for example addDatabase) and you'll be able to have database connection in all classes that you've passed Registry object.

Of course you can for some classes object pass only selected registry objects not the whole registry

Comment: It's a nice idea to add a new level and share generic objects - probably not what I'm after for this project, and not really any better for what I need. But I'll consider this for larger projects. Thanks Marcin.

Answer (score -1):

create a php Global $log maybe

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php